# How do I make one python dictionary to csv with headers?

Tags: python, database, csv, logging

I've been sitting for some time with a task to import serverlogs from a .txt file, write it out to a python dictionary and write it further out to a csv file to make it readable in a database. When I open it in fx. excel, I want it to be listed with headers.

EDIT: I need this to be generic in the way that I can load a log file of any length and still get everything. Edit done.

I'm stuck at the part of writing the dictionary down to the csv file. My following script looks like the following, and the seperated, out commented files are tries i've used to make it write it out.

```
    lineArray = []
    timeArray = []
    typeArray = []
    whoArray = []
    idArray = []
    msgArray = []

    infile = open('C:\SomeArea\data.txt', 'r')
    dictionary = {'time','type','who','id','msg'}
    for line in infile:
        timeInString = line[:24]
        timeInStringStripped = timeInString.strip()
        timeArray.append(timeInStringStripped)
        allTimes = ', '.join(timeArray)

#The last 4 fields was removed here to take less space

    infile.close()
    dictionary = {'time': allTimes, 'type': allTypes, 'who': allWhos, 'id': allIds, 'msg': allMsgs}
```

Half attempts to write it to the csv

```
#<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>#
#str = 'lement1, lement2'
#arr = ['lement1, lement2']

#import csv
#f = open('sometest2.csv', 'wb')
#wtr = csv.DictWriter(f, dictionary.viewkeys())
#for element in dictionary.viewitems():
#    print element
#    for e in element:
#        print e
#wtr.writerow(0)
#f.close()
#wtr.writerows(allTimes)
#wtr.writerows(allTypes)
#wtr.writerows(allWhos)
#wtr.writerows(allIds)
#wtr.writerows(allMsgs)
#print dictionary

#<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>#

import csv
f = open('sometest2.csv', 'wb')
wtr = csv.DictWriter(f, dictionary.viewkeys())
for row in dictionary: f.write("%s%s" %(delimiter.join([row[name] for name in fieldnames]),lineterminator))
```

Comment: I wrote this http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577996-ordered-csv-read-write-with-colum-based-lookup/?in=user-4177968 don't know if it's exactly what you need, but it allows for some easier manipulation and column based indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the code attempts to write a dictionary of lists and `csv.DictWriter` expects a list of dictionaries.

The right way to parse your data to work with the `csv` module would be to store each row as a dictionary. Hence instead of having something like this:

```
dictionary = {'time': allTimes,
              'type': allTypes,
              'who': allWhos,
              'id': allIds,
              'msg': allMsgs}
```

You should have something like this:

```
data = [{'time': time_row_1,
         'type': type_row_1,
         'who': who_row_1,
         'id': id_row_1,
         'msg': msg_row_1},

        ...

        {'time': time_row_n,
         'type': type_row_n,
         'who': who_row_n,
         'id': id_row_n,
         'msg': msg_row_n},
       ]
```

Hence, the code to read from a file should be like:

```
data = []
for line in infile:
    row = {}
    row['time'] = ...
    row['type'] = ...
    ...
    ...
    data.append(row)
```

and the code to write to a file would be:

```
wtr = csv.DictWriter(open(filename, 'w'), keys)
wtr.writerows(data)
```

Comment: The allTimes, alln was to make it an automated process, for logs of different length. Is there a way to make an automated process with csv.DictWriter, as I can't see it automated with time_row_1, _row_2 and so on?